# Cygwin Makefile Outputs gibberish?

Tags: cygwin

I have the following makefile vars, and the corresponding Makefile is correct. When I run the make command, nothing is happening. The gibberish output is displayed in an image below. Is there something that I'm missing?

```
####################
# Common variables
#################### 
#CC = icc
CC = gcc
#CC = cc
MAKE = make
#MAKE = gmake

# Compiling in 64-bit by default
FLAGS = -O3 
LDFLAGS = -O3

LIBS = -L../sprng2.0-lite/lib -lsprng -lm
INCS = -I../sprng2.0-lite/include

SSCADIR = SSCA2
SPRNGDIR = sprng2.0-lite
RANDDIR = random
RMATDIR = R-MAT

###########################
# SPRNG-specific variables
###########################

F77 = g77
FFLAGS = $(FLAGS)
F77LDFLAGS = $(LDFLAGS)
CFLAGS = $(FLAGS)
CLDFLAGS = $(LDFLAGS)
AR = ar
ARFLAGS = cr
SHELL = /bin/sh
RANLIB = ranlib
CLD = $(CC)
F77LD = $(F77)
FFXN =  -DAdd_
FSUFFIX = F
MPIF77 = $(F77)
MPICC = $(CC)
```

When I use Cygwin's make command, I get this output. Why is that happening? 
[image]

Comment: Use `make -help`. Ordinary usage: `make <targets>` or `make -f Makefile` or just `make` for the first target.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so the problem had nothing to do with Cygwin. It seems like Cygwin can only be used when the System Locale of a Windows Machine is set to English. 
To fix this problem, go to:

`Date and Time -> Advanced Options -> Change System Locale (preferably to English United States)`

Comment: unlikely. It works in any locale, and you can have a different locale for your Cygwin from the Windows one. May be you need to specify a UTF-8 locale. What is the output of `echo $LANG` ?

Comment: Ditto. Cygwin works in any locale, especially if it's a UTF-8 locale. Also, I recommend using the mintty terminal emulator that comes with Cygwin, and not the windows cmd.exe console. Unfortunately the cygwin.bat shortcut runs the latter for historical reasons, but I would not recommend using it. Instead make a shortcut to run `mintty.exe -` where the `-` is a shortcut meaning "run a login shell"